# Can i join one server with multiple ethernet wires to switches

Tags: networking, lan, ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I saw one video where the `user` has one `100mb switch` and other `Giagbit switch`.

Then he has his all servers `first network card` connected to `100mb switch` and second to the
`Gigabit switch`

he says that with normal switch the server will communicate to inetrnet and with second for the faster LAN data transfer

I could not understand How will the server know which interface to use for LAN and which for internet

Answer (score 0):

Each interface is connected to different networks, i. e. the 100Mbit NIC is configured for the network 192.168.0.0/24 and the GBit Nic is configured for 192.168.1.0/24. Now the machine knows that packages going to any of the addresses from the 192.168.1.0/24 network must be sent through the GBit interface and packages going to any of the addresses from the 192.168.0.0/24 network must go through the 100MBit interface.

Besides this the server has a default gateway, which is an IP address on one (and only one) of the configured networks, where the server will send any packages he doesn't know what to do with, e. g. a package for IP 8.8.8.8 (this is one of Google's nameservers.) In our scenario this is on no network the server knows about, including any static routes, so he sends it to his default gateway. The default gateway knows what to do with this package and if not it will send the package to its default gateway and so on. Sooner or later the package will cross the boundary from you LAN to the WAN of your ISP. The ISP in turn will route the package to 8.8.8.8 and tell 8.8.8.8 where to send any response.

For details read a little bit more. This is a good introduction to practical networking: http://aboutdebian.com/network.htm but you should also read up on the OSI layers and general computer networks. This Wikipedia article, esp. chapter 7,  is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network